# What do these MS DTC Exceptions mean?

Tags: exception, transactionscope, msdtc

I wrote a program to demonstrate the behavior of DTC timeouts with multiple threads.  I'm getting several exceptions, seemingly at random.  Are all of these simple Timeouts, or are some of them indicative of deeper problems (connection pool interactions, etc)?

> The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.
>
> Distributed transaction completed.  Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction.
>
> The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.
>
> The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
>
> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Here's the data part of the code:

```
using (DemoDataDataContext dc1 = new DemoDataDataContext(Conn1))
using (DemoDataDataContext dc2 = new DemoDataDataContext(Conn2))
{
  WriteMany(dc1, 100);  //generate 100 records for insert
  WriteMany(dc2, 100000);  //generate 100,000 records for insert

  Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", Name, " generated records for insert.");
  using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
  {
    dc1.SubmitChanges();
    dc2.SubmitChanges();
    ts.Complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're leaking connections (opening, but never closing "something").  This is definitely "Bad" ;)  But I'm not sure what you *should* be doing to fix it :(

Comment: Conn1 and Conn2 are strings.  WriteMany adds records via InsertOnSubmit... the records aren't related to anything.  There is sufficient data that I expect timeouts.  The exceptions do occur at the expected time of the timeout.

Comment: This pattern of datacontext creation and transactionscope use is what I asked about over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693811/am-i-using-transactionscope-and-datacontext-properly

Answer (score 0):

All these exceptions tell me that you have memory leaks. For me, these exceptions are not just some simple timeouts, I think you should search for deeper problems.

`ts.Complete()` does not guarantee a commit of the transaction. 
It is merely a way of informing the transaction manager of your status. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx

Is it an issue that you informed the transaction manager that your transaction is complete when it actually isn't?